Is there a way to optimize this query in Tsql?
WITH CTE AS
(
   WITH flattened_data AS 
   (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        MAX(CASE WHEN (entry.value:Id::STRING)='123' THEN entry.value:Answer:text::STRING END) AS VD,
        MAX(CASE WHEN (entry.value:Id::STRING)='3456' THEN entry.value:Answer:text::STRING END) AS DPL,
        MAX(CASE WHEN (entry.value:Id::STRING)='8971' THEN entry.value:Answer:text::STRING END) AS DL_Date
    FROM TABLE_FCA,
         LATERAL FLATTEN(input => COLUMN_TX:Question) AS entry
    WHERE entry.value:Answer:text IS NOT NULL
        AND entry.value:Id IN ('123','3456','8971')
  GROUP BY COLUMN_TX
  HAVING VD IS NOT NULL
  )

SELECT VD,MAX(DPL) AS DPL ,MAX(DL_Date) AS DL_Date 
FROM flattened_data GROUP BY VD

)

Select * from
TABLE_A A
Join TABLE_B B ON...
.
.
.
.
.
LEFT JOIN CTE ON CTE.VD=A.VD

The reason why it is done like this is beause the TABLE_FCA doesn't have a unique key and COLUMN_TX has a json value.
There could be multiple json records having the same VD and could have differrent DL_Date.
using a CTE inside a CTE and then using it in another JOIN feels like there could be an easier way which iam missing.
I tried using CTE inside a CTE. Iam not sure if there is a better way this could be done like using a temp table.

This doesn't look like sql server, removing that tag

No need to nest your CTEs like that, but I'm not sure whether that changes the execution plan or not.  Without seeing sample JSON data for what you are flattening or what your expected output should be, it hard to assist you here.  It'd also help if you were to indicate from the execution profile what the longest running steps are.
